# Git - Recover Deleted branch from local and remote

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Can I get my deleted git branch back, I deleted it from local and remote repository.

Answer (score 12):

Run `git reflog` to find the **sha1** of the commit that was on the top of your deleted branch, then just run `git checkout -b <branch> <sha1>` and you're all set.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.. I really blundered up until your answer rescued me